# Unable to create the model within its associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model which has_one Post model, which belongs_to User. Through a before_save callback, I want to create an (actually multiple, but this is another question) empty (or better, default like saying "This is my first post") Post, whenever a new user signs up. But the function below:

```
def create_post
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  @post.user = self
  @post.save
```

gives an error:

undefined local variable or method `params' for #

What might the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to the params hash in the model.

You don't want to do this in an `after_save` callback, but in a `after_create` or `before_create` I'd say.

Also, I don't understand why a User has_one Post... especially if you want to create several.

In the callback:

- if a user has_one :post

  `self.create_post(default_values_hash)`
- if has_many :posts

  `self.posts.create(default_values_hash)`

Comment: Right, should have has_many. But why not before_save? I thought that before&after_create callbacks carry the risk of creating orphan posts, if sth goes bad and the user does not get saved.

Comment: before_save would be executed every time you save your user, when you update it etc. If you use after_create, I think there is no risk the user has not been saved. If you used before_create, you could do `self.posts.build({})` instead of `.create` so that the post won't be created if the user isnt.

Comment: I see, before_create is better than, I think. Just to extend a little, is it okay to do: self.build_post or self.posts.build({rating => (5..12).to_a.sample"}) to get a random value?

Comment: I think so... Dont forget the `:` before `rating`.